# AngularJS scope variable undefined in page load for other function

Tags: angularjs

Im trying to get initialize the scope variable via http get request in page load in first function but then when trying to use the scope variable in other function in the same page load, it is undefined.

```
app.controller('GradeAndSectionCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {

    $scope.GetCategories = function () {
        $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: '/GradeAndSection/GetCategories'
        }).then(function (response) {
            $scope.categories = response.data;
            if (response.data != null) {
                $scope.drpCategory = $scope.categories[0].categoryID;
                                    }
        });
    };

    $scope.GetGrades = function () {
        \\$scope.drpCategory; here; is; undefined;
        $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: '/GradeAndSection/GetGrades?categoryID=' + $scope.drpCategory
        }).then(function (response) {
            $scope.grades = response.data;
        });
    };

    $scope.GetCategories();
    $scope.GetGrades();
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are making asynchronous call using promises in your code therefore $scope.drpCategory may not be loaded when you call GetGrades function. You can call your GetGrades function when GetCategories is resolved.

```
$scope.GetCategories = function () {
        $http({
            method: "GET",
            url: "/GradeAndSection/GetCategories"
        }).then(function (response) {
            $scope.categories = response.data;
            if (response.data != null) {
                $scope.drpCategory = $scope.categories[0].categoryID;
                $scope.GetGrades();
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer

Comment: I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

Try to call the function `GetGrades` in `then()`

```
 $scope.GetCategories  = () => {
    $http
        ({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'categories.json',
        })
        .then(data => {
            $scope.categories = data.data;
            $scope.drpCategory = $scope.categories[0].category
            $scope.GetGrades($scope.drpCategory)
        }, function errorCallback(response) {
            console.log(response);
            console.log('error');
        });
 }
 $scope.GetGrades = (drpCategory) => {
   $http
      ({
          method: "GET",
          url: "categories_" + drpCategory + ".json"
      }).then(function (response) {
          $scope.grades = response.data;
          console.log($scope.grades)
      });
}
 $scope.GetCategories()
```

Working example: http://plnkr.co/edit/ZN8nI7OhAyWiJWlqeJsU?p=preview

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer

Comment: @IcerExiomo 